# List index splitting

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, split, python-3.5

I am trying to return a sentence length `<=` of a list index using the `split()` method. If i input the exact length of a certain index, this works but `<` doesn't seem to do anything. Here is my code:

```
stories = [['With bloody hands, I say good-bye.'],
['TIME MACHINE REACHES                FUTURE!!! ... nobody there ...'],
["Not In My Job Description: Make sure it's done by the end of the day Jones.\nBut, sir, it's not in my ....\nJust do it, and remember, no blood."]]

def len_sentence():
    search = int(input("Enter int"))
    for i in stories:
        len1 = (i[0][0:].split(' '))
        if len(len1) <= search:
            print(i)
len_sentence()
```

User input of integers 1-5 returns nothing. If I replace `<=` with `>=` this works. Why doesn't `<` do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inputs you're trying are too small. The shortest story you have there is 6 words long, so inputs 1-5 won't match anything. The code looks fine to me though, it's just your search inputs.